# Connect Timeout does not work

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a report query and it takes more than 15 seconds (default value for timeout) to run. I added 'Connect Timeout' parameter to my connection string in web.config but it did not make any difference. The query still times out in 15 seconds.

> connectionString="server=xx.xx.xx.xx;database=yyy;User
>   Id=zzz;Password=vvv;**Connect Timeout=60**"
>   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Any suggestion?

PS: I am using SqlCommand object to run the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the timeout for *establishing a connection*, not executing a query.  You can set the *command* timeout using the [`CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: I already have it in place but that makes no difference either.

CommandTimeout = 600

Comment: Is there a timeout set at the database server?

Answer (score 0):

To what i see is that you are missing a semicolon over your paramter.

connectionString="server=xx.xx.xx.xx;database=yyy;User Id=zzz;Password=vvv;Connect Timeout=60"; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: name="LocalDB" connectionString="server=xx.xx.xx.xx;database=yyy;User Id=zzz;Password=vvv;Connection Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 

Also, connect timeout is just for establishing connection with your DB Server. To set timeout limit on your query, you need to set a command timeout using SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property. This cannot be achieved through your web.config file.